# Laravel: Controller or Middleware

Tags: laravel, controller, middleware

I'm using Laravel 6.9.0. This is my payment controller:

```
class PaymentController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('payment.test');
        $this->middleware('payment.check');
    }

    public function pay(){
        $this->payment->pay();
    }

    public function refund(){
        $this->payment->refund();
    }

    public function checkOrder(){
        $this->payment->checkOrder();
    }
}
```

The `payment.test` middleware does these:

1. write request log
2. check if the merchant exists
3. decrypt requset

The `payment.check` middlware is used to check which payment it is, like applepay or googlelpay.

But from the official documentation, middleware is used to filter HTTP requests,
verifies the user of your application is authenticated.

It seems `payment.check` does not belong to this. Thus, I change `payment.check` middleware to the controller. Because all the methods have to check payment,I put it in the constructor. However, I must decrypt the request before I check it,
so my constructor now is

```
$this->middleware('payment.test');

$this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
    $this->checkPayment($request);

    return $next($request);
});
```

`checkPayment` looks like this:

```
private function checkPayment($request){
    if($request->aaa == 'aaa'){
        switch($request->type){
            case '001':
                $type = 'apple';
                break;
            case '111':
                $type = 'google';
                break;
            ...

        }
    }else{
        switch($request->code){
            case 'android':
                $type = 'android';
                break;
            ...
        }
    }


    $this->payment = app($type);
}
```

It makes my controller ugly. I feel writing it to middleware looks more modular and clear. Is writing it to controller really better than middleware? Or any other suggestions?

Comment: I'm guessing $this->payment is the paymentProvider implementation? and if so do you have a main interface, abstract class or similar for it?

Comment: Yes,it's a paymetsProvider implementaion.I do have an interface and an abstract class, all payments must extend the abstract class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i see it your whole problem is, to instantiate the correct implementation even thou your logic does that in the end by calling `$this->payment = app($type);`. The core concept is still in this context, which provider do you need. There is many options to to this, service, factory etc. but to do a container provider version of this, is really powerful and clean when you are in `Laravel`.

Imagine having your `PaymentProviderInterface`, i would bind this to resolve which payments provider to use. Combine that with that you in any context can resolve the request object and you can move all this to a provider, i would create a new one. `PaymentProvider` and register it as any other provider.

```
class PaymentsProvider {
    public const APPLE_PAYMENT_PROVIDER = 'apple';

    public const GOOGLE_PAYMENT_PROVIDER = 'google';

    public const ANDROID_PAYMENT_PROVIDER = 'android';

    public function boot() {
        $this->app->bind(PaymentProviderInterface::class, function () {
           /** @var Request $request **/
           $request = resolve(Request::class);

           $type = null;

           if($request->aaa == 'aaa') {
               $type = $this->resolvePaymentByType($request->type);
           } else {
               $type = $this->resolvePaymentByCode($request->code);
           }

           return resolve($type);
        });
    }

    private function resolvePaymentByType(string $type): string
    {
        if ($type === '001') {
            return static::APPLE_PAYMENT_PROVIDER;
        }

        if ($type === '111') {
            return static::GOOGLE_PAYMENT_PROVIDER;
        }

        throw new Exception('Invalid state');
    }

    private function resolvePaymentByCode(string $code): string
    {
        if ($type === static::ANDROID_PAYMENT_PROVIDER) {
            return static::ANDROID_PAYMENT_PROVIDER;
        }

        throw new Exception('Invalid state');
    }
}
```

In general i don't like switch cases, you can use them if you like i think this is more clean. Another minor optimization instead of having magic strings use constants, it is more readable and has a lot of upside. Since we bound everything to the `PaymentProviderInterface`, this would make your controller really clean by resolving your provider like this. To avoid conditions where you don't have a request, i would inject in each method.

```
class PaymentController extends Controller
{
    public function pay(PaymentProviderInterface $payment){
        $payment->pay();
    }
```

Comment: There is a lot of assumptions in this post, but atleast i hope i can get you closer to something cleaner, i believe that the cointainer provider solution is gonna serve you the most and makes it really easy to mock if you want to do that :)